# Unable to deploy war file on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

Hi Previously I was using tomcat 7 and was deploying my war file on tomcat 7(on linux server). Now I have installed tomcat8(on linux server) but Its not deploying my war file. My Configurations are:

The last one in following image is my Web application.

m[image]

**My Web.xml file is:**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
    <display-name>DL Access</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                 com.dl.pretasks.PreTasks
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.dl.dlaccess.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.dl.contentTags.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.dl.contentTags.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet3</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.dl.changeApiStatus.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dl/dlaccess/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dl/content/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dl/content/cron</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet3</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/apistatus/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
    <location>/defaultErrorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**My Pom.xml File is:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>svc</groupId>
    <artifactId>svc</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>svc Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId> <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId> 
            <version>0.9.0</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-signals</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1-incubating</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.98.4-hadoop2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>svc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Tomcat Log File:**

```
16-Nov-2014 20:27:44.985 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
16-Nov-2014 20:27:44.987 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:   Sep 24 2014 09:01:51
16-Nov-2014 20:27:44.987 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:  8.0.14.0
16-Nov-2014 20:27:44.987 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:        Linux
16-Nov-2014 20:27:44.987 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:     3.13.0-37-generic
16-Nov-2014 20:27:44.987 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:   amd64
16-Nov-2014 20:27:44.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:    1.7.0_67-b01
16-Nov-2014 20:27:44.988 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.295 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was n$
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.520 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-22410"]
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.536 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.539 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.543 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.543 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 636 ms
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.568 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.569 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
16-Nov-2014 20:27:45.609 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/svc.war
SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.074 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.080 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/svc] startup failed due to previous errors
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.091 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/svc.war has finished i$
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.094 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/docs
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.145 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/docs has finis$
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.146 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/examples
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.437 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/examples has f$
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.437 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/ROOT
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.460 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/ROOT has finis$
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.460 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/manager
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.491 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/manager has fi$
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.491 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/host-manager
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.516 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /etc/tools/tomcat-8.0.14/webapps/host-manager h$
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.526 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-22410"]
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.535 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.540 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 4996 ms
```

Locally on my ubuntu machine this web application is running fine on tomcat. But when i delpoy it on ubuntu server and want to access then it starts creating 404 error. I dont think that there is some problem with web.xml or pom.xml because in that case it should not have deployed on my local machine.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: "SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart" - why not fix this issue as a first step?

Comment: @eis Hi, But my application was working in local tomcat 8 with same  warning of both log4j and did not mentioned any error about listener start. But why it giving this error on server?

Comment: don't really know. You'll need to debug it further and provide us with more details. Attach a debugger to your Tomcat and find out what's the problem.

Comment: @eis Thanks for your comments. I checked my localhost.2014... file and it contains the error which is caused due to log4j conflict. I will try to first remove this thing and then will come back to you if there is still a problem.

Comment: @eis Can you post an answer? coz your point got everything right for me. slf4j was the main problem and its solved now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem. Added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.074 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
16-Nov-2014 20:27:50.080 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/svc] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Fixing this conflict between the .jars should be the first step. One or the other should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use below tags in POM.xml

```
<exclusions>
<exclusion> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
```